# How to parse DOM in OPA?

Tags: opa

I've just now started with OPA and I want to parse a DOM, but I can only get elements by the id, with `Dom.get_value(#an_id)` for example. What if I have a layout like the one in the chat example on the tutorials:

```
    <div class="line">
      <div class="user">{x.author}:</div>
      <div class="message">{x.text}</div>
    </div>
```

How can I get the text that is in the message div? I've tried Dom.get_value(Dom.select_class("line").select_class("message")), but I get this error:

```
    Error
    File "chat.opa", line 29, characters 49-62, (29:49-29:62 | 714-727)
    Record expression has type dom but field access expected it to have type
    { select_class: 'a; 'r.a }.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First :

[`Dom.get_value`](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#stdlib.core.xhtml.dom.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.xhtml.Dom.get_value) only works on `input` or `textarea` tags.

In your case, you should call [`Dom.get_text`](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#stdlib.core.xhtml.dom.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.xhtml.Dom.get_text) on your `div`.

However, if you want to get the content without wondering if you have an input/textarea or not, just use [`Dom.get_content`](http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#stdlib.core.xhtml.dom.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.xhtml.Dom.get_content)

Moreover, you can't do :

> Dom.select_class("line").select_class("message"))

You can do :

> Dom.select_class("message")

or

> Dom.select_raw(".line > .message")